# How to iterate through lists?

Tags: iteration, sml, smlnj, currying

I am trying to learn standard ml of new jersey, but I don't understand how to iterate though lists.

I am trying to create a function that takes a value and a list of functions, and returns another list of strings, if the current function returns true when given the value.

A function is like this `('a -> bool) * string`, i.e. a pair of the function and a string of its name.

The function is a curried function so its defined like "fun itr x xs".

I want to do this non-recursively.

Can anyone help me start?

Comment: Why do you want to do it non-recursively? ML's list structures are naturally recursive.

Comment: I am pretty sure that there is no such thing as "non-recursive" in SML. There are no loop control flow structures. As stated below, you could use foldr, but that is just a higher-order function that uses recursion.

Comment: You can write imperative code in Standard ML, but it's not pretty. There are both `while` and `ref`, so e.g. `val x = ref 0; val _ = while !x < 10 do x := !x + 1`.

Comment: @SimonShine: True, though the *Definition* defines `while ... do ...` as a "derived form" of `let val rec vid = fn () => if ... then (...; vid()) else () in vid() end` -- i.e., declaring a tail-recursive function *vid* and then calling it -- so it's arguably still recursive.

Answer (score 1):

A natural and straightforward function for this could be written fairly easily with recursion.

```
fun itr x fs =
  case fs
    of [] => []
     | (f, s) :: fs' => if f x
                        then s :: itr x fs'
                        else itr x fs'
```

Or, if you don't want to explicitly recurse in your function, you could use `foldr`.

```
fun itr x fs =
  List.foldr (fn ((f, s), ss) =>
    if f x
    then s :: ss
    else ss) [] fs
```

Also, `itr` isn't a very informative name, so you may want to choose a different one that better describes what it is you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

So, if I understand correctly, you want to be able to call your function like this:

```
itr
    3
    [ ((fn i => i > 3), "greaterThanThree"),
      ((fn i => i mod 2 = 1), "odd"),
      ((fn i => 12 mod i = 0), "dividesTwelve")
    ]
```

and get a result like `["odd", "dividesTwelve"]` (since `odd` and `dividesTwelve` are the two functions that return `true` when applied to `3`).

Do I have that right?

So, we can start by writing:

```
(* Given a value and a list of named Boolean functions, returns a list of the names of the
 * functions that return true for value.
 *)
fun itr value namedFunctions =
  ...
```

Since you say that you want to "do this non-recursively", I assume that what you mean is that you want to use the list functions in the Standard ML Basis Library that let you process lists by providing functions that handle list-elements in isolation; those functions are implemented using recursion, of course, but if `itr` just delegates to them, then `itr` itself need not be recursive.

Given those requirements, I see two approaches.

---

One approach is to start by using `List.filter` ([see `List.filter` documentation here](http://sml-family.org/Basis/list.html#SIG:LIST.filter:VAL)) to get just the elements of `namedFunctions` that return `true` when called on `value`. To do this, we need a function that takes a named function (a `('a -> bool) * string`, where `'a` is the type of `value`) and returns `true` if the named function returns `true`; that is:

```
(* A function that, given a named Boolean function, returns whether it returns true for
 * value.
 *)
fn (f, _) => f value
```

That lets us call `List.filter` like so:

```
(* A list of the elements of namedFunctions that return true for value. *)
List.filter (fn (f, _) => f value) namedFunctions
```

Once we have that, we need to use `List.map` ([see `List.map` documentation here](http://sml-family.org/Basis/list.html#SIG:LIST.map:VAL)) to get just the name of each function:

```
(* A list of the names in namedFunctions that return true for value. *)
List.map #2 (List.filter (fn (f, _) => f value) namedFunctions)
```

(where `#2` is the function to extract component `2` of a tuple or record; in the case of a named function, `#2 namedFunction` is the name).

Putting it together:

```
(* Given a value and a list of named Boolean functions, returns a list of the names of the
 * functions that return true for value.
 *)
fun itr value namedFunctions =
  List.map #2 (List.filter (fn (f, _) => f value) namedFunctions)
```

---

Another approach is to combine both the filtering and the mapping into a single step, by using `List.mapPartial` (see [`List.mapPartial` documentation here](http://sml-family.org/Basis/list.html#SIG:LIST.mapPartial:VAL)). Instead of first selecting just the elements we want by using a function that takes a named function and returns a Boolean, and then converting them to the form we want by using a function that takes a named function and returns its name, we can combine the steps by using a function that takes a named function and returns its name *only if we want it*.

In Standard ML, when we want to represent a value that doesn't always exist, we use `option`; for example, `string option` means "either a string, or nothing" ([see `Option.option` documentation here](http://sml-family.org/Basis/option.html#SIG:OPTION.option:TY); note that, although it's documented as `Option.option`, it's also available as just `option`). So, here's a function that takes a named function and returns its name only if it returns true for `value`:

```
(* A function that, given a named Boolean function, returns its name if it returns true
 * for value, and nothing if it returns false.
 *)
fn (f, name) => if f value then SOME name else NONE
```

Such a function is called a "partial function" — it returns a value for only *part* of its domain — and we can use `List.mapPartial` to retrieve its results for only those cases where it returns one:

```
(* Given a value and a list of named Boolean functions, returns a list of the names of the
 * functions that return true for value.
 *)
fun itr value namedFunctions =
  List.mapPartial (fn (f, name) => if f value then SOME name else NONE) namedFunctions
```

In general, any time that you want to apply `List.map` to the result of `List.filter` or vice versa, you can combine both steps by using `List.mapPartial`. (In any given instance, however, it may or may not be a good idea to do so. I recommend whichever one is clearer.)